# can't get nested views to work with ui-router

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have been able to switch out my angular router code with ui-router and it works fine with a basic setup.  But on my page I have a partial that I want to reuse in multiple views and I can't get that working.  Can anyone see an issue with my code below.

routes....

```
$stateProvider
.state( 'jobs', {
    url: '/jobs',
    templateUrl: templates.jobs,
    views: {
        'jobs': {
            templateUrl: templates.jobList,
            controller: 'JobListController'
        },
        'alert': {
            templateUrl: templates.alert,
            controller: 'AlertController'
        }
    }
})
```

templates.jobs file...

```
<div ui-view="jobs"></div>
<div ui-view="alert"></div>
```

and then the templates.jobList and templates.alert are just regular html blocks.

I have a main page with just a  where my app initially loads.  It's within this ui-view that I want to load the templates.jobs view along with it's nested views.

I've found that if I remove the templateUrl: templates.jobs from my jobs state and then move the two ui-views from that jobs file to my main html file it works.  However, my main file needs to be able to load many potential views - the ui-view on the main html is just a placeholder where the rest of the application lives.  So I can't have those two ui-views in my main file.  Is there a way to make this work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also set the parent view of `jobs` state in the views object and use absolute targeting:

```
$stateProvider.state('jobs', {
    url: '/jobs',
    views: {
        '@': {
            template: '<div ui-view="jobs"></div><div ui-view="alert"></div>',
            controller: function () {}
        },
        'jobs@jobs': {
            template: '<h2>Joblist</h2>',
            controller: function () {}
        },
        'alert@jobs': {
            template: '<h2>alert</h2>',
            controller: function () {}
        }
    }
});
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AR8RK1Ik1xeGL0xUBV6e?p=preview

Reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names

Comment: Thanks so much.  I had come across that multiple named views article after I posted my question but still couldn't quite get it to work.  Your code was the missing link.  Thanks again!

Comment: No thanks, you're always welcome, this is what SO is for. Glad i could be of assistance. FYI: That's not just an article it's the actual wiki from the ui-router repository. Could come in very handy at times. Good luck with your project!

Comment: The reference link was exactly what I needed to solve a similar problem. I'm glad UI Router is robust enough to support nested ui-view references.